# Bundle install/update not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

Taking a rails tutorial, and I've run into the following problem that I'm having trouble figuring out. I'm creating a sample app that's supposed to use the following gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
 end

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end 

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

When I tried to "bundle install --without production" per instructions, though, I get this

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
>    In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
>      activesupport (3.2.3)
>
> In Gemfile:
>      rails (= 3.2.5) ruby depends on
>        activesupport (= 3.2.5) ruby
>
> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
>   the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

So I tried updating, but I was told that:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
>    In Gemfile:
>      rails (= 3.2.5) ruby depends on
>        railties (= 3.2.5) ruby
>
> jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
>        railties (3.2.6)

So I tried to update my gems via rvm, figuring that was the problem. (Did "rvm rubygems current"). But that didn't seem to fix anything.

Help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `bundle update` explicitly? Upgrading to 3.2.6 is a must as well, as it include security fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.5'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked. If you don't mind, could you explain briefly why that worked? I'd love to understand what was at the root of that problem and why changing the rails version fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Of course, if it's a pain, don't bother. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. Railties is included with the Rails gem. Since you were originally installing rails 3.2.5, you were getting railties 3.2.5 with it. However, jquery-rails 2.0.0 needs railties 3.2.6 to run. By changing rails 3.2.5 to rails 3.2.6, you then get railties 3.2.6 installed and this eliminates the jquery-rails problem.

Comment: Cool. Didn't realize that was a think you could do on stackoverflow. Obviously I'm new at this. And thanks for the answer.